# How can I declare a set of Objective-c blocks in a separate file and include that file in my code?

Tags: objective-c, block, grand-central-dispatch

I have a set of Objective-C named blocks which I need across multiple viewControllers. These named blocks will get executed via `dispatch_async()`.

Instead of declaring them multiple times, I would like to declare them once (such as in an `NSObject` subclassed .h/.m combination) and then `#import` them like any standard subclass.

How can I do this? This is driving me nuts. I've tried several ways, but the solution keeps evading me. Please help!

Thanks
Shaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.h` file, declare your block variables like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

extern int (^intReturningBlock)(int foo, int bar);
extern NSString* (^stringReturningBlock)(int foo, int bar);
```

And in your `.m` file, create the block variables:

```
#import "MyBlocks.h"

int (^intReturningBlock)(int foo, int bar) = ^int(int foo, int bar) {
    return foo + bar;
};

NSString* (^stringReturningBlock)(int foo, int bar) = ^NSString*(int foo, int bar) {
    NSNumber* tmp = @(foo + bar);
    return [tmp description];    
};
```

My hunch is that the part you're missing is the `extern` on the declarations. This site is a useful reference: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! It works now. I was indeed missing the extern. Thank you very much, impcc!